# C++ Winsock Library Termination When connecting with Putty Client on 127.0.0.1

Tags: c++, server, client, putty, winsock

I'm trying to create a server client that once its working I can pass a vector into it and send it to a client program through ssh like putty. The issue is whenever I try to connect raw or ssh with putty on 127.0.0.1:45000 the program terminates once it connects.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    // Initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't Intitialze winsock! Quiting" << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Create a socket to bind
    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << endl;
    }
    // Bind the socket to an ip address to the port
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(45000);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; // could also use inet_pton

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    // Tell winsock the socket is for listening
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    // Wait for connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];  //Clients remote name
    char service[NI_MAXHOST]; // Service (port) the client is on

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXHOST); // use mem set of linux

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " <<
            ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Close listening socket
    closesocket(listening);
    // while loop; accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[4096];
    while (true)
    {
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

        // wait for client to send data
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client Disconnected, bytes 0" << endl;
            break;
        }
        // echo message back to client
        send(clientSocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);

        // Close the socket

    }
    closesocket(clientSocket);


    // Shutdown winsock
    WSACleanup();
}
```

I'm writing it and compiling in Visual Studio 2019.

Here's the message I get from Putty when trying to connect with the ssh option or raw.

[image: Picture of Puttys error when trying to connect.]

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have `return;` statements in `main` after you have connected, effectively shutting down the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `getnameinfo()`, you are `return`'ing from `main()` immediately, without calling `closesocket()` first, regardless of whether `getnameinfo()` is successful or fails.  This is the root of your Putty error.  You are explicitly exiting your app whenever a client connects, without informing the client that the connection is being closed.

More generally, if `accept()` is successful (and `socket()`, too), you should *always* call `closesocket()` on the returned `SOCKET`, regardless of anything else happening in your code (same with `WSACleanup()` if `WSAStartup()` is successful).

There are several other mistakes in your code:

- It is *illegal* for `main()` to have a non-`int` return type (though *some* compilers allow this, as a non-standard extension.  Don't rely on this!).
- You are missing a `return` from `main()` if `socket()` fails.
- You are not checking for errors on `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`, or `send()`.
- There is no point in setting the backlog to `SOMAXCONN` if you are only going to `accept()` 1 client ever.
- you have a potential buffer overflow when calling `send()`. Imagine if `recv()` returned *exactly* 4096 bytes received.  Sending `bytesReceived + 1` number of bytes back to the client would go out of bounds of your `buf` array.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int errCode = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (errCode != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't initialize winsock! Error " << errCode << ". Quitting" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Create a socket to bind
    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        cerr << "Can't create listening socket! Error " << errCode << ". Quitting" << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    // Bind the socket to an ip address to the port
    sockaddr_in hint = {};
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(45000);
    hint.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // could also use inet_pton

    if (bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        cerr << "Can't bind listening socket! Error " << errCode << ". Quitting" << endl;
        closesocket(listening);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    // Tell winsock the socket is for listening
    if (listen(listening, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        cerr << "Can't open listening socket! Error " << errCode << ". Quitting" << endl;
        closesocket(listening);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    // Wait for connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        cerr << "Can't accept a client! Error " << errCode << ". Quitting" << endl;
        closesocket(listening);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];  //Clients remote name
    char service[NI_MAXHOST]; // Service (port) the client is on

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXHOST); // use mem set of linux

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, clientSize, host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client.sin_addr), host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }

    // Close listening socket
    closesocket(listening);
    listening = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // while loop; accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[4096];
    while (true)
    {
        // wait for client to send data
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            errCode = WSAGetLastError();
            cerr << "Error reading from client: " << errCode << ". Quitting" << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client Disconnected" << endl;
            break;
        }

        // echo message back to client
        char *ptr = buf;
        int bytesToSend = bytesReceived;
        do
        {
            int bytesSent = send(clientSocket, ptr, bytesToSend, 0);
            if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                break;
            ptr += bytesSent;
            bytesToSend -= bytesSent;
        }
        while (bytesToSend > 0);

        if (bytesToSend != 0)
        {
            errCode = WSAGetLastError();
            cerr << "Error writing to client: " << errCode << ". Quitting" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Close the client socket
    closesocket(clientSocket);

    // Shutdown winsock
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a c++ noob so this is a eye opener. This code is for a personal exploit that one of my courses requires me to write. it won't see any public use.